# Raspberry Pi Acess Point with TP-Link TL-WN722N

Tags: pi-2

This has been a nightmare to make work for some reason, and I thought I was finally there until...

It seems I have an access point running at long last, I can connect through my Windows machine no problem...but it seems when I try with my Android phone it keeps connecting and disconnecting and connecting again in an endless cycle.

Any clues?

**hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=XXXXXX
hw_mode=g
channel=11
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=XXXXXXXXX
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
wpa_ptk_rekey=600
macaddr_acl=0
```

**interfaces.d**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

**dhcp.conf**

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.0.0.25 10.0.0.50;
option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4;
option routers 10.0.0.1;
interface wlan0;
}
```

Regards,
Matt

Comment: can you show the contents of wpa_supplicant.conf?

Comment: I removed it as it is supposed to cause conflicts with hostapd

Comment: Removed as in before I even posted this.